# Topologicclad clasp property

Tags: general-topology

If $\tau_{X}$ is the topology in $X$ then the subspace topology in any $Y\subset X$ is the induced topology:

$$\tau_{Y}=\{T\cap Y:T\in \tau_{X}\}$$

This follows that the closed in $Y$ are:

$$\overline{\tau_Y}=\{Y\backslash (T\cap Y):T\in \tau_{X}\}$$

So if $Z\subset Y\subset X$ then $Cl_{Y}(Z)=Y\cap Cl_{X}(Z)$.

I wonder why it's worth the equality $Cl_{Y}(Z)=Y\cap Cl_{X}(Z)$?

Comment: Sorry, what is the question here? I don't understand what you mean by "why it's worth". And what is the title supposed to mean?

Answer (score 2):

**Proposition.** [2.2.1, Eng] Let $X$ be a topological space and $M$ a subspace of $X$. The set $A\subset M$
is closed in $M$ if and only if $A=M\cap F$, where $F$ is closed in $X$. The closure $\tilde{A}$ of a set
$A\subset M$ in the subspace $M$ and the closure $\overline{A}$ of $A$ in the space $X$ are related by the equality
$\tilde{A}=\overline{A}\cap M$.

*Proof*. If $A =M\cap F$, where $F =\overline{F}\subset X$, then $M\setminus A=M\cap (X \setminus F)$ and $A$ is
closed in $M$ as the complement of an open set. Conversely, if $A$ is a closed subset of $M$, then
$M\setminus A = M\cap U$, where $U$ is open in X. Thus
$$A = M\setminus(M\setminus A) = M\setminus (M\cap U) = M\cap(X\setminus U),$$
and $A = M\cap F$, where $F = X \setminus U$ is closed in $X$.

By definition of the closure operator, $\tilde{A}$ is equal to the intersection of all closed subsets
of $M$ that contain $A$, i.e., of all sets $M\cap F$, where $F = \overline{F}$ and $A\subset F$. This gives the equality
$\tilde{A} = M\cap\overline{A}$. $\square$

*References*

[Eng]  Ryszard Engelking, *General Topology*, 2nd ed., Heldermann, Berlin, 1989.

Comment: Okay, thank you!!!!